# visit buffer without setting mode in script

Tags: script

I'm trying to write a small program to indent lisp files using `lisp-mode` so I can get Emacs-compatible indentation even when using a different program.

Here's my first attempt to write a program to visit a file, override its mode and, indent it, and then write it back.

I'm wondering if there's a way to non-interactively open a buffer to a file without enabling the modes associated with that file. It seems more elegant than enabling `text-mode` and then `lisp-mode`.

```
#!/bin/sh
:;exec /usr/bin/env emacs -Q --script "$0" "$@"

(mapcar (lambda (filename)
          (find-file filename)
          (text-mode)
          (lisp-mode)
          (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
          (basic-save-buffer))
        argv)
```

I copied the file into `indent2.el` and ran `indent.el` a few times with `indent2` as an argument.

It seems to be working correctly, but produces the message

```
> ./indent.el ./indent2.el
Setting up indent for shell type sh
Indentation variables are now local.
Indentation setup for shell type sh
Indenting region...
Indenting region...done
```

which means that Emacs is processing the shebang even when being used non-interactively. Is there a way to get it to bypass that step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert-file-contents` to read text from file and `write-region` to write text to file. User commands like `find-file` / `save-buffer` / `write-file` have many interactive features thus usually are supposed used by user directly, i.e., via key binding or `M-x`, not from Lisp code.

```
(defun my-indent-lisp-file (filename)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filename)
    (lisp-mode)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (write-region nil nil filename)))
```

By the way, if your code is in Emacs Lisp, you should use `emacs-lisp-mode`. `lisp-mode` is for Common Lisp, I think.

Comment: Thank you. When using the script on a copy of itself though, I still see the `Setting up indent for shell type sh` message (because of the `#!` preamble). It seems to be coming from the `write-region` command and there doesn't seem to be a way to suppress it. I think it's harmless though.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet That message doesn't come from the above code, it stills shows if you keeps only the first two lines.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet For the sake of simplicity, I suggest using `#!/usr/bin/env emacs --script`, if it doesn't work, use `#!/path/to/emacs --script`. Don't worry about portability if you are the only one who will use the script.